# Changing Mybatis/Spring DTD configuration from ibatis-3-config.dtd to mybatis-3-config.dtd breaks mapper injection (Invalid bound statement)

Tags: spring, bind, mybatis, code-injection, mapper

Today I am using the following dtd declaration inside my mybatis-configuration.xml:

```
<!--DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/ibatis-3-config.dtd" -->
```

But using this approach does not allow me to configure my mappers as:

```
<mappers>
    <package name="com/app/integration/persistense" />
</mappers>
```

And without this capability, I am obligated to declare each xml mapper one by one.

So I decide to give a try with:

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
```

With this I can declare the package tag with no problem. But here comes the odd. I have a @Configurer class that has inside of it a @Service that consequently has a MyBatis mapper object (interface).

With the first approach (ibatis DTD) the injection works like a charm, but changing the declaration as described I get this exception during the app startup:

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
**Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.app.integration.persistense.ConfigurationMapper.list**
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:189)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:43)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:51)
```

So I found a possible explanation here [MyBatis-Spring + @Configuration - Can't autowire mapper beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999597/mybatis-spring-configuration-cant-autowire-mapper-beans) but this does not make sense since the only difference here is the dtd declaration and the mapper path, I mean, is this enough to completely change how Spring and MyBatis are working together?

**Any ideas how to perform the changes and keep the injection working?**

My libs are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

First I updated from mybatis 3.2.7 to 3.2.8 and additionally, looking better, my package mapper tag name value could be wrong!

```
<mappers>
    <package name="com/app/persistense" />
</mappers>
```

Thus I did the following test, knowing that I have the right package name already working with version 3.2.8, then I downgraded to version 3.2.7, and guess what, It does not work. So even considering that I named my package wrongly, the mybatis version matters.

Best Regards.